# How do I trigger Alarms (In Alarm Clock) in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am building an Alarm Clock using Angular 2 JS. I am pretty much done but now I have all the Time (Time that we set alarm) in an array.

On iterating the array, I can access all the "Time" the alarms will notify, but what is the best way to trigger them? I only want to show a simple Alert at the particular time. This is my array which has all the times. I will subtract the value with the current time and pass the milliseconds to the SetTimeout() function.

1) What are the best ways to do this?

2) If upon iterating, I call the Set Timeout function, again on next iteration won't the previous alarm's value be over written with the current iteration?

3) What do you think is the ideal structure and logic to trigger the alarms?

```
ngOnInit() {

    var all =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
        for(var i =0; i < all.length; i++){
           var hours = all[i]['hours'];
           hours = new Date(hours).getTime();
           console.log(hours);
       }

  }
```

Here is the SetTimeout Function

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.FlashMessage.show('ALARM CLOCK WAKE UP', {cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout: 5000});
    }, milisec);
```

Answer (score 1):

So firstly if you're looking for best practices I would suggest you to put your iteration code to the Service instead of declare it in the `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook inside of the component class.

Secondly you should think about expired alarms. So you need to create a method like `checkAlarms(): number[]` which gonna filter your time comparing to the current. So here you could realize any logic for missing alarms delete or simply skip them.

So final step is executing the `SetTimeout`. As mentioned before I'll suggest you to decouple the logic. For example:

*component.ts*

```
constructor(private alarmService: AlarmService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  let time = new Date().getTime()
  this.alarmService.setUpAlarms(time);
}
```

*service.ts*

```
@Injectble()
export class AlarmService {
   constructor(private flashMessage: FlashMessage) {}

   public setUpAlarms(currentTime: number): void {
        this.savedAlarms
               .filter(alarm => this.checkAlarm(alarm, currentTime))
               .forEach(time => 
                  setTimeout(() => this.flashMessage.show(
                     'ALARM CLOCK WAKE UP', 
                     {cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout: 5000}
                 )}, time))
   }

   private get savedAlarms(): number[] {
        let alarms = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
        return Object.keys(alarms).map(param => {
             let time = alarms[param].hours;
             return new Date(time).getTime();
        });
   }

   private checkAlarm(alarm: number, currentTime: number): boolean {
        if (alarm < currentTime) {
           // do_something_here
           return false;
        }
        return true;
   }    
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, can you help me a little bit? I created the service but I am unable to understand how to proceed further.

Comment: That should help you: [guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#register-providers-component)

Comment: @ArtemLanovyy do you have sample output?